# Changing a const char with a void function

Tags: c, function, char, void

I'm trying to understand the following code and how functions, void and char work together. I was wondering if it was possible to change the char output from 'a' to char 'b', with just editing the void function? I have tried `void foo(char *x) {  *x = 'b';}`, however I receive an error saying 'core dumped', which I am confused about.

If it is impossible to change the `const char ch = 'a';` value, how would you change the value of  `char ch = 'a'` ?

Thank you~

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char x) {
  x = 'b';
}

int main() {
  const char ch = 'a';
  foo(ch);
  printf("ch = %c", ch);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to change the value of something you declared `const`? That defeats the point of making it `const`

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The code is not trying to change a `const` value, but a copy that is local to the function.

Comment: You likely received the error because the value of `ch` was stored in a read only memory region. By explicitly making `ch` a `const` the compiler was perfectly allowed to do so. By attempting to write to the read only region you likely triggered an access violation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do this only by changing the function. You need to change the function to take a pointer, change the caller to pass the address of the variable, and change the variable to non-`const`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char *x) {
  *x = 'b';
}

int main() {
  char ch = 'a';
  foo(&ch);
  printf("ch = %c", ch);
  return 0;
}
```